# NestJS matching route with different wildcards

Tags: parameters, routes, nestjs

Hello I want to match a route in NestJS like this:

```
@Controller('posts')
export class PostsController {
  @Get(:id)
  getPostById() {}

  @Get(:slug)
  getPostBySlug() {}
}
```

The problem is the request nevers hit the slug route, how can I configure the routes to make the id only match with numbers and the second only match with letters and dashes?

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 7):

It looks like there is a path-to-regex package in @nest/common dependencies and I checked - you can really use it.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp

Now you're able to make id match only numbers by setting regex:

```
@Get('/:id(\\d+)')
```

I didn't found the feature description in NestJS official docs, but it works. My @nest/common package versions is 8.4.1.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible, because when Express or Fastify sets up the router for this, it's just looking at something that matches a regex, and there's no qualifier that says "this is specifically a `slug`" or "this is definitely an `id`" so all Express or Fastify can do is match the first route. You would need to set up either a switch in your controller or service to call either method depending on the param, or you would need to make the routes identifiable before the use of the URL parameter. `@Get('/id/:id')` or `@Get('/slug/:slug')`

Comment: oohh I see, thank you man, I come from php laravel background and I used to use a where clause to define that kind of things so the request match with one or another accordingly, but if that's not possible in the nodejs world, well, I suppose we have to live with that lol.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with Nest's routing decorators, however you can access the underlying express or fastify instance and create a route using their native methods:

https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/http-adapter

https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.route

https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Routes/